# Memoize multi-line method - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memoization

I've never implemented memoization before using rails, and I think I came across a good use case for it but I'm not sure how to do it. Here is what I'm working with:

#### METHOD:

```
 def manager_rep_code_and_name
    manager = []

    rep_code_list.each do |rep_code|
      context = Finfolio::GetManagerByRepCode.call(rep_code: rep_code)

      manager.push({name: context.manager.response.first["Name"], rep_code: rep_code})
    end

    manager
  end
```

This method makes a network call and can potentially take awhile to figure all this out. Is there a way I can `memoize` this method so if it already exists I don't have to go out and make this request again.

#### Something like this:

```
def manager_rep_code_and_name
   @managers ||= manager = []

   rep_code_list.each do |rep_code|
     context = Finfolio::GetManagerByRepCode.call(rep_code: rep_code)

     manager.push({name: context.manager.response.first["Name"], rep_code: rep_code})
   end

  manager
end
```

Obviously, that doesn't work but I'm a bit stuck at the moment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I often separate such methods:

```
def fetch_manager_rep_code_and_name
  rep_code_list.map do |rep_code|
    context = Finfolio::GetManagerByRepCode.call(rep_code: rep_code)
    { name: context.manager.response.first['Name'], rep_code: rep_code }
  end
end

def manager_rep_code_and_name
  @manager_rep_code_and_name ||= fetch_manager_rep_code_and_name
end
```

Usually, this also makes them easier to test.

Answer (score 10):

You can use a `begin` `end` block to memoize the result of multiple lines of code:

```
def manager_rep_code_and_name
   @manager_rep_code_and_name ||= begin
     manager = []

     rep_code_list.each do |rep_code|
       context = Finfolio::GetManagerByRepCode.call(rep_code: rep_code)

       manager.push({name: context.manager.response.first["Name"], rep_code: rep_code})
     end

    manager
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. The only one here using `||= begin` :) seems not very well known still..

Answer (score 1):

Memoization is a little more complex if you want to memoize separate input/output pairs for the same function. Since you have no input here and the output is expected or allowed to be the same each time, memoization is very simple though. Something like this:

```
  def manager_rep_code_and_name
    return @manager if @manager
    @manager = []
    rep_code_list.each do |rep_code|
      context = Finfolio::GetManagerByRepCode.call(rep_code: rep_code)
      @manager.push({name: context.manager.response.first["Name"], rep_code: rep_code})
    end
    @manager
  end
```

It's a common convention to name the memoized instance var to an underscore version of the method name - `@_manager_rep_code_and_name`, in this case.

Answer (score 1):

```
 def manager_rep_code_and_name
    @managers ||= []
    if @managers.blank?
      @managers = rep_code_list.map do |rep_code|
        context = Finfolio::GetManagerByRepCode.call(rep_code: rep_code)
        {name: context.manager.response.first["Name"], rep_code: rep_code}
      end
    end
    @managers
  end
```

variable name is named to `@managers` from `@manager` because that contains a list of data.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `then` which will return the value of the given block.

```rb
def manager_rep_code_and_name
   @manager_rep_code_and_name ||= [].then do |managers|
     rep_code_list.each do |rep_code|
       context = Finfolio::GetManagerByRepCode.call(rep_code: rep_code)

       managers.push({name: context.manager.response.first["Name"], rep_code: rep_code})
    end
  end
end
```